# Consumindo API com Refit C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Boa pessoal, eu estou com um pequeno problema para consumir uma API.

Estou com uma aplicação web AspNetMVC e preciso consumir uma API.

Primeiramente com uma seleção do usuário eu executo este método abaixo no controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ChamadaTrade(String valor)
    {
        if (valor != null)
        {
            var saida = APICalling.Call();
            return Json(saida);
        }
        else
        {
            var saida = "falha";
            return Json(saida);
        }
    }
```

A intereface para implementação da chamada:

```
 public interface IApiService
{
    [Get("")]
    Task<Data> GetDataAssync();
}
```

E o método que a implementa:

```
[HttpGet("")]
    public static async Task<string> Call()
    {
        try
        {
            IApiService ExchangeClient = RestService.For<IApiService>("https://api.coinlore.net/api/tickers/");
            var dataExchange = await ExchangeClient.GetDataAssync();
            return dataExchange.Name.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return $"Erro na consulta dos dados " + e.Message;
        }
    }
```

No entanto estou recebendo *JSONException "jsonexception a possible object cycle was detected which is not supported"*

Só queria saber se meu código tem alguma implementação errada ou se preciso fazer alguma conversão do JSON que não estou fazendo.

Comment: Olá, é uma configuração no JSON. Teu objeto, provavelmente, está com referencia circular Ex.: class Pai { public List<Filho> filhos {get;set; } e class Filho { public Pai pai {get;set; }; Quando o programa vai transformar o objeto em JSON string, vai ficar em um loop entre as referencias dos dois objetos. Vai precisar ignorar o erro no serialize do objeto para evitar esse tipo de referencia circular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o Anderson Koester já falou, possivelmente sua classe Data está com referencia circular. Deveria ser algo parecido com esse exemplo:

```cs
public class Data {
    public string id { get; set; } 
    public string symbol { get; set; } 
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public string nameid { get; set; } 
    public int rank { get; set; } 
    public string price_usd { get; set; } 
    public string percent_change_24h { get; set; } 
    public string percent_change_1h { get; set; } 
    public string percent_change_7d { get; set; } 
    public string price_btc { get; set; } 
    public string market_cap_usd { get; set; } 
    public double volume24 { get; set; } 
    public double volume24a { get; set; } 
    public string csupply { get; set; } 
    public string tsupply { get; set; } 
    public string msupply { get; set; } 
}

public class DataResponse    {
    public List<Data> data { get; set; } 
}
```